# How do you duplicate images in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have 5 of the same images in a row (can i say div?)

```
<body>
    <div><img src = "picture.jpg";>
    /* code that duplicates or deletes multiple copies of "picture.jpg" */
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: CTRL C + CTRL V.

Comment: is there some code that can duplicate without having me to duplicate the same code? Because then I would have a lot of img src codes to keep track of.

Comment: Use `Loop` or `For` or `While` or anything that loop

Comment: It's certainly possible to clone the images in JavaScript, but why would you want to? The JavaScript code to duplicate the images would actually result in **more** code in total. Simply having five different `<img src=''>` (which JavaScript would compile the code to anyway) would allow you to change one of the sources in future if necessary without changing the others.

Comment: *"code that duplicates or deletes"* - Huh? Are you duplicating or deleting? Or is your requirement to call some function `setNumberOfImages(n)` that adjusts the total number of images up or down as appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like that:

```
<div id="list"><img id="item" src = "picture.jpg"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function cloneItem() {
      var item = document.getElementById("item");
      var list = document.getElementById("list");
      var clonedItem = item.cloneNode(true);
      list.appendChild(clonedItem);
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cloneItem();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: oh geez that looks really advanced